# mysql command is not found in terminal mac

Tags: python, mysql

I want to use mysql to get the access to google cloud and link it to python but i faced this message in terminal
How can i download mysql command ?
i already download the mysql shell but still this message appear.

```
rag@rags-MacBook-Pro ~ % mysql --version
zsh: command not found: mysql --version
```

Comment: you have a typo on your command, you forgot to put a space after the "mysql". It should be: `mysql --version`

Comment: If you just type `mysql` you should be able to access the db. If you have a password set use `mysql -p` and it will ask for the password For this specific command you forgot a whitespace between `mysql` and `--version`. It should be `mysql --version`

Comment: even without the whitespaces still shown not found                                       rag@rags-MacBook-Pro ~ % mysql
zsh: command not found: mysql

Comment: You don't have MySQL installed properly.  Believe the Mac.

Comment: So how to download mysql?

Comment: To download and install mysql, you can follow the instructions here, as pointed out in the answer below: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macos-excerpt/5.7/en/macos-installation.html

Answer (score 8):

To install mysql on mac, follow the official guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macos-excerpt/5.7/en/macos-installation.html .

After mysql is installed this way, you might still have to add the path to it to `~/.zshrc` in order to be able to use that command from `zsh`.

To add the path to `~/.zshrc` you can:

- `nano ~/.zshrc`
- Add the following line at the end of `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/<your_mysql_folder>/bin
```

where you substitute `<your_mysql_folder>` with the name of the folder where mysql was installed, in my case `mysql-8.0.28-macos11-arm64`

- Save and close the edited file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close)
- Update by either restarting the terminal or doing `source ~/.zshrc`

After this, the `mysql` command might work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it happened to be so that even after adding `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/<your_mysql_folder>/bi` in ~/.bash_profile file it was throwing the same error.

I had to fire `source .bash_profile` from terminal and it got fixed!! :)

Answer (score 0):

firing source.bash_profile from terminal worked in my case.

Comment: It surely did not work. And without the typo, that answer is a clone to one answer already given 5 months ago. Be sure, when answering to old question to bring new information that was not already present in existing answers.