# zsh: command not found: mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, zsh

using monteray 12.6

putting

`mysql --version`

into the terminal gives me

`zsh: command not found: mysql`

but if i do

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --version`

i get

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql  Ver 8.0.31 for macos12 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

which works

folder paths

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WWPC.jpg

my .bash_profile

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WWPC.jpg

`export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/"`

.zshrc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HYl1.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71156432/mysql-command-is-not-found-in-terminal-mac

putting ```source .bash_profile``` in the terminal after fixes it until you quit terminal again...

Comment: I don't see how your .bash_profile is relevant, when you use zsh. Contrary to _sober_ I would recommend against sourcing .bash_profile in your zsh. If you make this a habit, you are forced to write your .bash_profile in a way that it is compatible with zsh and bash, and this will soon become a nuisance (believe me, I tried a similar approach, and in the end caused me more headache than advantage).

Comment: im now trying to use zsh profile to create a path but when i do echo $path it doesn't show up

Comment: Has this profile being read by your zsh?

Comment: I suggest that you post in your question your zsh setup (what command is in which startup file), and how your zsh is invoked - otherwise a diagnosis is just blind guessing.

Comment: added more images to the bottom of the question

Comment: Don't add images. Add code. And don't show your .bash_profile. Nobody needs it. Also your screenshot of the file manager is unnecessary.

Comment: Plus, your images only show the content of the files. You should first show the variable of the PATH variable, then show how you invoke a zsh subshell, and then show again the content of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

put
`export PATH=/usr/local/mysql-8.0.31-macos12-x86_64/bin:$PATH`
in .zshrc file

thanks to user
user1934428
for taking the time to reply to me

Comment: (1) If you do this **only**, and then run an interactive zsh subshell from your zsh, the mysql directory would occur twice in the PATH. To avoid this, also add the statement `typeset -aU path`. (2) Also note that your PATH setting would only be honoured for an interactive zsh, or a non-interactive shell which has an interactive zsh as its parent. If this is too restrictive for you, put the PATH definition into ~/.zshenv instead.